# How to create rotating file logger on iOS 7/8?

Tags: ios, logging, log-rotation

I am developing a Beta iOS (7 and 8) app which will be handed to testers soon.

I would like to have a <kbd>send feedback</kbd> button which will send the developers a human description of what went wrong, along with the recent log files.

[image]

Since writing log files can consume a lot of space, I would like to [rotate the files based on their size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation), like the [Linux logrotate utility](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html). That is, write the first N log lines to a `app.log`, then rename `app.log` to `app.log.1`, delete the old `app.log.1` and continue writing to a new `app.log`.

This way I will have at most `2N` log lines in the iOS filesystem, and on my error reports.

**Is there an open-source, production-ready tool for file log rotation on iOS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack it's fast, flexible and very easy to setup and use.

Comment: Thanks! Does it support file rotating based on size?

Comment: Of course check out their API - DDFileLogger class has APIs like -
    setMaximumFileSize, setRollingFrequency, setMaximumNumberOfLogFiles which gives you great flexibility.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/LogFileManagement.md), but I am looking for something more specific.

Comment: What specific thing you were looking for ? https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md

Comment: There's time based log rotation, but no size based rotation at that page.

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CocoaLumberjack/2.0.0-beta/Classes/DDFileLogger.html#//api/name/maximumFileSize